# Cannot run createdb against tar file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I hear that `createdb` is better to run against live a database instead of `pg_restore`.. I have this command:

```
PGPASSWORD="$db_pwd" createdb -U "$db_user" -h "$db_host" -p 5432 --no-password -e "$db_name"
```

but I am getting this error:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)
CREATE DATABASE platform_production_backup_2;
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4034; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION pg_trgm 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension pg_trgm
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_trgm IS 'text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams';
```

so what does this error mean:

> ERROR:  must be owner of extension pg_trgm

? why is it trying to use the extension or copy it?

Answer (score 0):

That error is harmless.

It means that you restored the dump as a user that is not a superuser, so you cannot set the comment on the (already existing) extension `pg_trgm`.